# Given a package, how do I figure out what its artifactId should be?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I'm converting an existing project to maven for building/dependencies/etc, and I'm trying to figure out how to list its dependencies.

I know a bunch of packages that it uses, but I'm not sure what artifact they would be contained in.  The groupId is pretty easy to figure out, but I feel like I'm guessing at what the artifactId should be.

Is there an easy way to figure out what the artifactId should be given a package name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the [Sonatype Repository](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html) and search for the class name.

Actually, I've just checked. [Jarvana](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/) provides better results.

Comment: ah, the class name, not just the package name.  Danke.